# Executing function several times

Tags: javascript

I can't get the following code working properly. Google didn't help unfortunately.

What I want is that the function is executed immediately, then again after everything has loaded (seems to be safer for a data saving option in mobile Chrome) and again anytime the window is resized.

I cut down the code extremely, so it's easy to see right away what's happening, while the code still basically does what it's supposed to.

But for example classList.toggle doesn't work here in Firefox and Chrome, it's not giving the class, only an empty class attribute. IE 11 gives the class correctly.

Thanks for any hints!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    }

p {
    color: black;
    }

body.state-2 p {
    color: red;
    }

h2 {
    position: static;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {

h2 {
    position: relative;
    }

}

</style>

<body>

<h2>Headline</h2>

<p>Hello</p>

<script>

function toggleState()
{
    var toggle = document.querySelector('h2');
    var container = document.querySelector('body');
    if (window.getComputedStyle(toggle,null).getPropertyValue('position') == 'relative')
    {
        toggle.setAttribute('role', 'button');
    }
    else
    {
        toggle.removeAttribute('role');
    }
    toggle.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        container.classList.toggle('state-2');
    }
    );
}

toggleState();
window.onload = toggleState;
window.onresize = toggleState;

</script>
```

Comment: So it' appears that *everytime* `toggleState()` is executed you add another event listener.  So based on your code, it adds 2 event listeners right away, then anytime the window resizes you add another listener.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. In a former version, which had worked properly, I had used onclick and onkeydown instead of addEventListener, would that be a better way here? Or is there any way to get the posted code working?

Comment: You only have to add the listeners once. So remvoe `toggleState();` and `window.onresize = toggleState;` but keep `window.onload = toggleState;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're adding a new listener on every resize event:

```
toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){...});
```

and you're also finding the elements again and again:

```
var toggle = document.querySelector('h2');
var container = document.querySelector('body');
```

You could use a closure to address both problems:

```
function toggleState(toggle) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(toggle, null).getPropertyValue('position') == 'relative') {
    toggle.setAttribute('role', 'button');
  }
  else {
    toggle.removeAttribute('role');
  }
}

function setup() {
  var toggle = document.querySelector('h2');
  var container = document.querySelector('body');

  toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    container.classList.toggle('state-2');
  });
  window.addEventListener('load', function() { toggleState(toggle) });
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() { toggleState(toggle) });
}

setup();
```

In this way the listeners are created just once, and the references to the elements are saved in a local variable inside the `setup` function.